# How get result in mysql query where field contain exact string

Tags: mysql, where-clause

i have a table such as:

```
id  |  std_class
-----------------------------------------
1   |  class 1,class 12,class 25,class 11
2   |  class 12,class 52,class 75,class 16
```

with this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM $table_name
WHERE std_class LIKE '%class 1%'
```

the result contain rows 1 and 2, because row 2 contain 'class 12' and this is like 'class 1'

but i need only rows that contain exactly 'class 1'

how get this result?

Comment: This kind of problem can be symptomatic of poor schema design. Just sayin'

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function.

```
SELECT *
FROM $table_name
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('class 1', std_class)
```